# Iterate over a JSON array (parsed with SwiftyJson) on SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have a problem when try to iterate over a JSON array (parsed with SwiftyJson) to create a VStack for each item (they are part of HStack with horizontal scroll). The JSON array its filled fine, but I never iterate over it I'll always get the error "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'".

I'm learning SwiftUI and I stock with this.

This is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var city = ""
  @State var hourly_weathers:[JSON] = []

  var body: some View {
    Text("\(city)")
    .onAppear(perform: {
        getData()
    })


    for hw in hourly_weathers {
      VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
        Text("\(hw.temp)")
      }
    }

   func getData() {
       .....
       self.city = json["currently_weather"]["city"].stringValue
       self.hourly_weathers = json["hourly_weathers"].arrayValue
   }
}
```

I tried using ForEach (has suggested in comments) but I get this error "Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'JSON' conform to 'Hashable'"

```
ForEach(hourly_weathers, id: \.self) { hw in
  Text(hw["interval"].stringValue)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look up SwiftUI's `ForEach`

Comment: What is City? It akso seems to me you have added getData() function inside body property, also you are returning two different type from body which you shouldn't do. Also, for should be forEach.

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for your response. I edit my question including missing information. I tried with ForEach has other user suggested, but still without working.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem creating a Dictionary and append each item of JSON array to it.

This is the code:

```
struct HourlyWeather: Identifiable, Decodable {
    var id = UUID()
    var interval: String
}

  @State var hourly_weathers_array = [HourlyWeather]()

  ForEach(hourly_weathers_array) { hw in
    Text(hw.interval)
  }

  func getData() {
  ...
    for hw in json["hourly_weathers"].arrayValue {
    let hwObj = HourlyWeather(interval: hw["interval"].string ?? "00:00")
    hourly_weathers_array.append(hwObj)
  }
}
```

After, you can use ForEach to iterate over the new Dictionary and create views.

Thanks